# Android eclipse clean removes AndroidManifest.xml changes

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I am building an Android app, that makes use of WebView to display a part of a web page from the internet.  After much mucking about, I finally figured out that I am supposed to add the following line to my AndroidManifest.xml

All is fine, I am happy.  However, I did a "clean" in Eclipse, and all of a sudden my app's web access stopped working again.  After a careful look through everything, I realized that the eclipse "clean" process re-creates the AndroidManifest.xml file.  Upon some thinking, this makes sense also.

Question - how do I enable my android app to permanently have "internet permissions", so that I don't have to go through this process every time?

Comment: Clean does not recreate `AndroidManifest.xml`. It recreates `R.java` and rebuilds afaik

Comment: It does, I just tried it..  I can ALWAYS reproduce it.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the file in its source location, not a copy in the build output folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're changing the wrong manifest file, that is the one in bin folder (i pointed out with an image :D).

You should change the one in the root.[image]